# Where does the apparent white stripe came from

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing an issue with a shadow effect in my design. Despite having applied a shadow effect, there seems to be a white background appearing in front of the shadow. This is puzzling to me because the purpose of a shadow effect is to create a sense of depth and dimensionality, yet the presence of the white background seems to be undermining this effect.

[image]

I'm seeking guidance on how to rectify this issue. Is there a way to ensure that the shadow effect appears without any obstruction in front of it? Perhaps there's a setting or adjustment that needs to be made to achieve the desired result. Any insights or suggestions you can provide would be greatly appreciated.[text]

```css
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.shadow-dark {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(48, 46, 77, 0.15);
}

.padd-15 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.about .about-content h3.title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.about .about-content .timeline-box {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.about .about-content .timeline-box {
  background-color: #fdf9ff;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e8dfec;
}
```

```html
<section class="about section" style="width: 50%;">
  <div class="about-content padd-15">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="education padd-15">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="timeline-box padd-15">
            <div class="timeline shadow-dark">
              time
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's just the way the shadow makes it **appear**. It makes the background darker thus apparently highlighting the "stripe". What do you think it should look like?

Comment: It would look better if you put the shadow on the outer container with the rounded corners.

Comment: As Paulie said, it is just an optical illusion. the shadow on the inner side is darker than on the outside. As such the higher contrast makes the element look brighter then it actually is. The contrast causes the optical illusion.

Comment: You can set the background of the shadow element to something resembling the color of the surrounding area, like so: .timeline { background-color: rgba(48, 46, 77, 0.05); }